# How to force dark-mode using TailwindCSS on browsers?

Tags: javascript, html, css, user-interface, tailwind-css

I have a [website](https://reubence.com) with proper implementation for dark/light UI using TailwindCSS.

I was wondering if there is a way to force the website to load in dark mode until the user specifically toggles light mode on by clicking the toggle button.

Why? Cause I prefer how the website looks in dark mode, but since the light/dark themeing is properly implemented I'd rather keep it and force it to load in dark mode despite user's browser settings.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try the following

In `tailwind.config.css` set the `darkMode` to `class`

```
module.exports = {
  darkMode: 'class',
  // ...
}
```

And when you need the `darkMode` just add `ClassName` of `dark` inside the `html` tag

```
<html className="dark">
<body>
  <!-- Will be black -->
  <div className="bg-white dark:bg-black">
    <!-- ... -->
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And when you need the `light` just remove `ClassName` of `dark` inside the `html` tag

Hope it helps!

Comment: Official documentation: https://tailwindcss.com/docs/dark-mode#toggling-dark-mode-manually

Comment: What in the world is a `css` file that has `js` and a html file with `className`?

Answer (score 8):

I tried the method of setting `darkMode` to `class` in the `tailwind.config.js` file as was suggested in another answer, but despite taking all the steps, this wasn't working for me.

In my case, all I needed to force dark mode in my app was to adjust the media queries in my `main.css` (AKA `globals.css` or whatever else you've called it).

```css
/* main.css */

@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;

/* All your tailwind definitions with @apply rules are here */


/* If the user prefers dark mode, 
we of course apply color-scheme: dark, as usual */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  html {
    color-scheme: dark;
  }
}

/* If the user prefers light mode, 
we still enforce color-scheme: dark, despite the user preference */
@media (prefers-color-scheme: light) {
  html {
    color-scheme: dark;
  }
}
```

That's it. I didn't need to mess about in my `tailwind.config.js` or anywhere else.